# How can I define multidimensional arrays in python?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array

In MATLAB there is an easy way to define multidimensional arrays e.g.

```
A(:,:,1) = [1,2,3; 4,5,6];
A(:,:,2) = [7,8,9; 10,11,12];

>> A

 A(:,:,1) =

 1     2     3
 4     5     6


 A(:,:,2) =

 7     8     9
 10    11    12
```

where the first two indices are respectively, for the rows and columns of the ith matrix (or page, see picture below) stored in A;

[image]

Does anybody know how can I define the same structure in python?

Comment: **Use NumPy**. It's like Matlab in Python.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

with NumPy indexing is similar to MATLAB

```
 import numpy as np
 A=np.empty((2,3,3))
 A.shape
 #(2L, 3L, 3L)
 A[0,1,2] # element at index 0,1,2
 #0.0
 A[0,:,:] # 3x3 slice at index 0
 #array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
 #       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
 #       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
 A[1,1,:] # 1-D array of length 3
 #array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]
```

Comment: Perhaps you should also show the `import` statement since you use `np` and it makes your answer "more canned". +1.

Comment: Also note that in MATLAB one generally indexes `A(x,y,z)` while python follows `A[z,y,x]` when doing maths

Comment: Yes, difference in the parenthesis and the brackets, but the indexing styles are same, also `matlab` uses 1-based indexing like `R` instead of `python`'s 0-based indexing.

Comment: This looks more like it! Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

A *pure Python* way to do this is using a list of lists (or in this case a list of lists of lists). You can initialize it with list comprehension. For instance:

```
w = 4 #width
h = 3 #height
d = 3 #depth

data = [[[0]*h for _ in range(w)] for _ in range(d)]
```

Or if you want to fill the *tensor* with tuples like on the figure:

```
data = [[[(i+1,j+1,k+1) for k in range(h)] for j in range(w)] for i in range(d)]
```

This initializes a `d` x `w` x `h` "matrix" filled with zeros.

You can then access the `(i,j,k)`-th element with:

```
data[i][j][k]
```

Nevertheless there are libraries like [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) that have support for vectors, matrices, tensors, etc.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer! Then I guess that what I am trying to do is a list of arrays, something like 

   A = [array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]), array([[5,6,7], [7,8,9]])]

However, is there a way to call only the first elements of each row of the first array in A? Something that in matlab would be A(:,1,1). Thanks!

Comment: @S88S: Not as far as I know. In that case you better use numpy: numpy is really meant for doing matrix,... calculations whereas Python itself is of course a general purpose programming language.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to use [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) then there's [plenty of ways](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-creation.html). One way would be to initialise with all zeros or, as in your updated example, you could also fill with a range and then [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(48, dtype=np.int64).reshape((3, 4, 4))
# or 
b = np.zeros((3, 4, 4), dtype=np.int64)
```