# Generate (NxN) array from (Nx1) array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Consider the following `(Nx1)` array:

```
a = [[1]
     [2]
     [3]
     [4]
     [5]]
```

How to generate an `(NxN)` array from `a`? For e.g. `N = 5`:

```
a = [[1 1 1 1 1]
     [2 2 2 2 2]
     [3 3 3 3 3]
     [4 4 4 4 4]
     [5 5 5 5 5]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to copy the values, you can use [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
>>> np.repeat(a, len(a), 1)
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]])
```

Else, you should perform a broadcast and wrap `a` with a view using [`np.broadcast_to`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html):

```
>>> np.broadcast_to(a, (len(a),)*2)
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
a = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
out = []
for el in a:
    out.append(el * len(a))
return out
```

It is even better if you compute the length of the 'a' list once at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

A pythonic one liner to generate the two dimensional array

```
a = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
N = 5
x = [i * N for i in a]
```

---

Sources:

[Python List Comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52541850/python-list-comprehensions)

[How can I define multidimensional arrays in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741319/how-can-i-define-multidimensional-arrays-in-python)